# How to include standard path in bazel

Tags: bazel

In my project, I want to use some commands which are installed via homebrew on Mac. Unfortunately, bazel doesn't include my modified classpath when I run commands via it. How can I enable such PATH with minimum amount of command line parameters and configurations?

Answer (score 2):

There's an --action_env flag which allows to specify environment variables. See more here: https://bazel.build/designs/2016/06/21/environment.html