# "Debuggin in unit test in flutter project "

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

"When i am adding the break point in the unit test file for debugging there is a Edit Configuration pop up and it is asking for Bazel path,where can i find the Bazel Path for flutter project in android studio ide"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include standard path in bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200987/how-to-include-standard-path-in-bazel)